# Expected output is not right in mysql in hackerEarth

Tags: mysql, sql

I am practicing in hackerEarth SQL and I came to this [image]

My answer is : `SELECT name FROM places WHERE rating >= 4.0`.

Why is it wrong? The expected output should be

[image]

what is something wrong in my query? Thank you

Comment: The "problem" includes the clause "made for hackers".  Should your query include something for that as well?

Comment: @David I got it what you mean. I will try to check again the table. Maybe my condition is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another condition in where clause along with rating>4
-Execute only "Select Category" and you will find the relevant info